# Can I build or write my code in such a way that it searches for a dll in a specific directory?

Tags: c++, dll, windows-10

I have an C++ application in `dir\executables`.
I have a dll in `dir\libraries`.
And in case it's important, my header files are in `dir\headers`.

When I copy my dll into `dir\executables`, the program runs just fine, but when the dll is not in the executables directory, I get an error complaining about being unable to find the dll.

Is there a way to write or build my program so that it takes responsibility for finding the dll itself without having to modify `PATH`, update the registry or copy the dll into the same folder as the executable?

Comment: why without modifying PATH? The question reads a bit like "how to solve the problem without applying the solution?"

Comment: What exactly prevents you from keeping that dll in the folder where executable is located? It is a common approach.

Comment: @user463035818: I am wondering if there is a way to make the program work "out of the box," without forcing end users to update their environment.

Comment: @AlexF I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @VTT: Nothing! I was just wondering if there are any _more_ solutions.

Comment: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

Comment: I've updated my question to (hopefully) more clearly convey what I'm asking.

Comment: Read the link @VTT shared. You can use `SetDllDirectory` then `LoadLibrary`.